# diff2html.py "simplediff not found" yet I know simplediff module is installed

Tags: python, svn, diff

I am trying to use diff2html.py to create an html file from an svn diff file but when i run it `./diff2html.py -i test.txt -o differences.html` I get an error message saying "info: simplediff module not found, only linediff is available
info: it can be downloaded at https://github.com/paulgb/simplediff" I have downloaded simplediff and I know it exists because I have run  `python -c "import simplediff` followed by `echo $?` and it return `0` which shows that I have the simplediff module. Any suggestions on how to get diff2html.py to run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem and the way I managed to make work was creating the `.diff` file as follows (note the **-u**):

```
diff -u file1 file2 > mydifffile.diff
```

Then feeding that `mydifffile.diff` to `diff2html.py` as follows:

```
cat mydifffile.diff | diff2html > myhtmlfile.html
```

Note that `diff2html` was added to the PATH

Comment: I ended up just ignoring the message and it still worked fine.